# Extract object attributes from list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have used the following expression to get all attributes of an object from a list of those objects starting with the second object in the list:

```
[elem.sig_name for elem in timeline[2:]]
```

However the result is a list of instancemethods instead of a list of strings with the attribute "sig_name"

Could anybody help me solve this?

Update:

This worked: `[elem.sig_name() for elem in timeline[2:]]`

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the type of objects in `timeline`. What happens if you do `elem.sig_name()` instead of `elem.sig_name`?

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So this worked:

```
[elem.sig_name() for elem in timeline[2:]]
```